# regex : how to format whole string not part of the string

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I am trying to format whole string but the format function is matching part of the string and format it.

I am adding below code sample :

```
import java.security.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import static java.text.MessageFormat.format;
public class A {
    private static String buildExprByField(String label,String predicate) {
        String expression = predicate;
        expression = expression.replace(label, format("isRuleLabelSuccess(\"{0}\")", label));

        expression = "!(" + expression + ")";
        return expression;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(buildExprByField("rule.1","rule.10"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
!(isRuleLabelSuccess("rule.1")0)
```

I am trying to get

```
!(isRuleLabelSuccess("rule.10"))
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why should it return `!(isRuleLabelSuccess("rule.10"))`? Even if the `replace` is removed, you would get `!(rule.10)`.

Comment: Is the _MessageFormat_ class required, or would a _[String#format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))_ suffice?  Is has a simpler format; _MessageFormat_ is commonly used with _Logger_ events, which typically requires heavier interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

```
expression.replace(label, format("isRuleLabelSuccess(\"{0}\")", label));
```

You replacing "rule.1" only, so you will get "isRuleLabelSuccess("rule.1")" and at the end "0" added as it was not part of selection.

**Solutions:**

1. You can pass "rule.10" as label

Or

2. `return "!(isRuleLabelSuccess(" + predicate + "))";`

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting, there is no *regex* here, this is referred to as *[string interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation)*.

You have *label* and *predicate*, swapped, within the method.

The *expression* value should be *label*.
And, the *format* method should be using *predicate*.

```java
private static String buildExprByField(String label, String predicate) {
    String expression = label;
    expression = expression.replace(label, format("isRuleLabelSuccess(\"{0}\")", predicate));

    expression = "!(" + expression + ")";
    return expression;
}
```

Output

```
!(isRuleLabelSuccess("rule.10"))
```

As a note, I'm unsure if *MessageFormat* is a requirement—it is typically used with heavy *string interpolation*, common to the *[Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html)* class.

The *[String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html)* class offers a much simpler set of methods, harnessed from the *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* class.
Specifically the *[String#format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))* and *[String#formatted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...))* methods.

Note, the syntax is different than *MessageFormat*.  And, is inherited from the *[C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language))*.

Here is a Wikipedia article on *[C-style formatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Syntax)*—also referred to as, *"printf format"*.
Additionally, the *JavaDoc* for *Formatter*—which I linked above—provides the exhaustive set of parameters.

Here is a basic example.

```java
expression = expression.replace(label, String.format("isRuleLabelSuccess(\"%s\")", predicate));
```

```java
expression = expression.replace(label, "isRuleLabelSuccess(\"%s\")".formatted(predicate));
```

As a final measure, here is a simpler way to code the entire task.

```java
return "!(%s)".formatted("isRuleLabelSuccess(\"%s\")".formatted(predicate));
```

Or

```java
return "!(isRuleLabelSuccess(\"%s\"))".formatted(predicate);
```

Comment: `String.format`/`formatted` is also a heavyweight operation. If you want a lightweight, efficient operation, just use `"!(isRuleLabelSuccess(\"" + predicate + "\"))"`

Comment: @Holger, I wasn't implying performance, I meant the syntax isn't as involved.

Comment: Hmm, replacing `{0}` with `%s` doesn’t look like a big deal, syntax-wise.

Comment: @Holger, for example, _{0,number,integer}_, versus _%d_.  Additionally, _C-style_ formatting is used within other languages as well.

Comment: In this specific example, it was just `{0}` vs `%s`. That was the whole point of my comment, “*`String.format`/`formatted` is also a heavyweight operation*”; using an engine for advanced formatting options not used here at all. And the change distracts from the OP’s actual problem. But since you mentioned it, “*is used within other languages as well*” is not necessarily an advantage, it can even be a disadvantage, as developers fail to recognize the differences on a regular basis. For example, there is no point in writing `%d` instead of `%s`, it makes no difference at all.

Comment: @Holder, great, are you going to write an answer?